# My XML file is not being by Google Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, google-chrome, local

I am making a simple javascript application where I need to load an xml files and show them in front of the user. but my code only works in Mozilla Firefox but when it comes to chrome and Internet Explorer they are not working. I am loading my XML document in a local machine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.buttons').slideToggle('medium');

    $.ajax({ 
    url: "dictionary.xml", 
    success: function( xml ) { 
        $(xml).find("word").each(function(){ 
            $("ul").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
        }); 
   } 
    });
}
```

And Here's my XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <xml> 

    <word> 
      <threeletter>RIP</threeletter> 
      <fourletter>PIER</fourletter>
      <fiveletter>SPIRE</fiveletter> 
      <sixletter>SPIDER</sixletter> 
     </word>

     <word> 
      <threeletter>SUE</threeletter> 
      <fourletter>EMUS</fourletter>
      <fiveletter>SERUM</fiveletter> 
      <sixletter>RESUME</sixletter> 
     </word>

     <word> 
      <threeletter>COO</threeletter> 
      <fourletter>CON</fourletter>
      <fiveletter>CONDO</fiveletter> 
      <sixletter>CONDOM</sixletter> 
     </word>

    </xml>
```

I found the error, here it is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/JsTwist/dictionary.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: Can you check for an error or something in the Chrome developer console? [Ctrl+Shift+J]

Comment: I think the error here is that google chrome doesn't allow access to local files? but I found this error XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/JsTwist/dictionary.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: but it is working in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Your XML is valid, it was just improperly formatted and it looked like you were missing the first two lines.  If you highlight your code in the text box and press CTRL+K, it will format it as code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome doesn't allow AJAX requests over the `file://` protocol by default.

You'll need to start Chrome with the `--allow-file-access` switch.

[Here are instructions](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) for supplying switches on each OS.

I'm not sure how to enable the file protocol for IE.

Possibly the easiest thing to do is to setup a local web server and run your app along with the xml files in it, then you don't have to worry about this issue in either browser.

**edit**

Late edit, I know.  I wanted to throw this out there in case others have an issue.

When requesting an xml document with jQuery, you should *always* supply a dataType in the settings object. Internally, jQuery does it's best to guess at what is returned and I've had it consider a perfectly good xml document to be HTML/XHTML.

To do this, add **dataType: "xml"**. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.buttons').slideToggle('medium');

    $.ajax({ 
        url: "dictionary.xml", 
        success: function( xml ) { 
            $(xml).find("word").each(function(){ 
                $("ul").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
            }); 
        },
        dataType: "xml"
    });
}
```

Supported data types are available on the documentation page for [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

In addition, I've encountered the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** error above when trying to fetch an RSS feed from a remote server.  The only way I've determined to get around this is to proxy request the RSS feed from the server-side code and deliver it via some proxy script.  Here's a simple example in PHP:

```
<?php

 if(isset($_GET['q']) && isAjax())
 {
    $q = strip_tags($_GET['q']);
    header("Status: 200");
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo  file_get_contents('http://'.$q);   
    exit();
 }

function isAjax() {
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
    ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'));
}

?>
```

**CAVEAT** I highly recommend modifying the above script to allow only those locations you plan to serve to your client code by validating `q` or by further restricting the `isAjax` function. I'm not a PHP developer and I don't pretend to know best practices for PHP security.  If anyone has suggestions to improve the PHP snippet, I'd happily apply them.

Comment: How would I --allow-file-access ? how would I do that ?

Comment: Did you follow the link? There are instructions for Windows, Linux, and Mac. If you're on Windows, navigate to your Chrome installation directory and run `chrome.exe --allow-file-access`

Comment: , the error while I was  adding the flag was " the name specified in the target box is not valid"

Comment: I'm in Ubuntu, so I can't reproduce this. If I remember correctly, Chrome in windows will have a target surrounded by quotes. You would have to add the switch after the quotes, `"C:\fakepath\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access`

Comment: Okay so I was able to add --allow-file-access but it is still giving me these errors. Jeez, Google chrome sucks >.>

Comment: @user962206 I just saw that you were still having issues although you replied an hour after my last visit to this question.  I updated my answer with a comment on requesting xml data via `jQuery.ajax()`.