# Is there a NumPy-like package for Node.js and if not why not?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've always been amazed at how much much much faster things become if you manage to rewrite code that loops though your ndarray and does something, with NumPy functions that work on the whole array at once. I'm looking for something similar in Node.js. So far I have turned up some things, none of which look promising:

- [scikit-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scikit-node), runs scikit-learn in Python, and interfaces with Node.js. I haven't tried it, it may not give me the speed that I would like.
- There are some rather old, and newer, JavaScript matrix libraries ([sylvester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scikit-node), [gl-matrix](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix), ...). In addition to not being sure they work well with matrices larger than 4x4 (which is most useful in 3D rendering), they seem to be native JavaScript (and some, not sure these, use [WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) acceleration). Great on the browser, not so on Node.js.

As far as I know, npms can be written in C++. I'm wondering why there are no NumPy-like libraries for Node.js? Is there just not enough interest in Node.js yet from the community that needs that kind of power? Is there a hope that ES6 features (list comprehensions) will allow JavaScript compilers to automatically vectorise native JavaScript code to C++ speeds? Am I missing something else?

I'm not asking for "what is the best package to do xyz". I'm just wondering if there is a technical reason there is no package to do this on Node.js, a social reason, or no reason at all and there is just a package I missed. Maybe to avoid too many opinionated criticism:

I have about 10,000 matrices that are 100 x 100 each. What's a reasonable fast way to add them together?

After some more googling for "Node.js scientific computing" there are links to some very interesting notes:

- https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/a-faster-leaner-javascript-for-scientific-computing-what-features-should-i-kee
- http://www.quora.com/Can-Node-js-handle-numerical-computation-the-same-way-that-languages-like-R-or-Julia-can
- [Javascript and Scientific Processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651081/javascript-and-scientific-processing)

Basically as far as I understand now, no-one has bothered so far. Also, since there are some major omissions in the js TypedArrays (such as 64bit ints), it might be hard to add good support by just using NPMs, and not hacking the engine itself—something that would defeat the purpose. Then again, I didn't further research this last statement.

Comment: Edge will support SIMD, if that's at all close to what you're talking about. also checkout [].map(), which can do stuff like `["A","B","c"].map(Function.call.bind("".toLowerCase))`

Comment: As far as I can see, edge is a node - .net bridge, right? I'm not sure how that helps.
I am familiar with the map() function call, but in my tests adding 2 matrices together this way doesn't even come close to the speed of doing the same thing numpy (which I can imagine; it must be extremely hard to figure out for the compiler what is going on in a reasonable amount of time).

Comment: whoops: Edge == IE12, i guess we must respect the rebrand now...

Comment: Ahhhh... I thought it sounded familiar .....

Anyways, what I remember from my work on llvm, I don't think any dynamic language will ever reach that level of performance, no matter how good the compiler.

Comment: asm can run llvm code at about 90% the perf of the original. it takes forever to load, but it runs fast. with webassembly, that load time will drop by 90% and the run perf will bump up slightly. dynamic languages from now on will be faster than pre-compiled code because of run-time optimizations that considers input that compilers don't have, while all the rest is still JIT and fast. you can also upgrade the perf of a dynamic app without recompiling (ex upgrading V8), which is a heck of a trade-off for that small and shrinking perf diff.

Comment: @Claude Did you have a look at [math.js](http://mathjs.org)? It's goal is to become the numpy of JavaScript. The current v1 does not have an impressive performance, but for the upcoming v2 there is a lot of progress there (sparse matrices, typed matrices, ...). You may also find http://numericjs.com/ interesting.

Comment: Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/numjs  numjs

Comment: Since numjs looks like pure javascript to me, I would expect it to give you just the numpy-interface, not the speed. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: Check Qminer (based on C++)- it supports linear algebra (matrix, vector operations), analytics, machine learning...  https://github.com/qminer/qminer

Comment: @snoobdogg I agree (especially since the "close" banner invites me to edit the question or delete it). Your remark has spurred me to [ask around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398332/should-i-edit-my-long-existing-highly-upvoted-closed-question) what I should actually do about this.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No, there are no technical reasons why a numpy-like package does not exist for Node.js and, more generally, JavaScript.

There are two main obstacles preventing Node.js and JavaScript from achieving more mind share in the data science and numeric computing communities.

The first obstacle is community. While the JavaScript community is huge, the subset of people within that community doing interesting things in numeric computing is small. Hence, if you want to do numeric computing in JavaScript and Node.js, finding resources to help you along the way can be hard, and it may feel like a lonely endeavor.

Next, the absence of comparable libraries (chicken and egg: libraries are needed to attract library authors and authors are needed to write good libraries). There are no technical reasons why libraries cannot be written in JavaScript or leverage Node.js (e.g., via native add-ons). I know, as I have written many numeric computing libraries in JavaScript. So while numeric computing is possible in JavaScript, the problem stems from an inability to attract developers having sufficient expertise and capable of putting in the time and effort needed to write high quality numeric computing implementations.

Regarding the specific language features mentioned in the OP:

- **ES6/ES2015**: none of the recent language additions help or hinder development of numeric computing libraries in JavaScript. Potential additions like list comprehensions will not be game changers either. The one change to the web platform which will make a difference is WebAssembly. With WebAssembly, compiling C/C++/Fortran libraries to run in web browsers will be made easier. At the time of this answer, WebAssembly looks to be the means for bringing SIMD to the web, potentially allowing some speed-ups, although the focus seems to be on short SIMD, rather than long. But even with WebAssembly, porting numeric computing libraries to the web will not be as simple as hitting the compile button. Numeric computing code bases will need to massaged to become amenable for use on the web, and, even then, higher level APIs will likely need to be written to mask some of lower level features, such as manually managing the heap.
- **Native add-ons**: yes, node modules can be written as native add-ons, allowing C/C++/Fortran code to be used within a Node.js application. Individuals have written libraries to this end; for example, see [stdlib](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib/tree/88c1a0ca14e19162600ecf0ec6530f2b3902f0e0/lib/node_modules/%40stdlib/math/base/blas/dasum). If done well, Node.js can perform numeric computations at speeds comparable to directly using native implementations.
- **Typed arrays**: as they are now, they are suitable for numeric computation. Similar to C, you can create pooled buffers, which allow for efficient memory reuse and better performance. Furthermore, similar to languages like R, Python, and Julia, you can leverage typed arrays to create ndarray (aka strided array) interfaces. While U/Int64 integer arrays are not currently available at the time of this answer, (a) their absence is not a show stopper and (b) proposals are advancing at the specification level to add U/Int64 integer arrays to JavaScript. Ditto for complex numbers with structured types.

My personal belief is that some form of numeric computing is inevitable in JavaScript and Node.js. The advantages (ubiquity, distribution, performance) and potential applications (edge computing, integrating machine learning, data visualization) are too strong of evolutionary forces not to support data science applications, at least at a basic level.

**disclosure**: I and others are currently working on a project (https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib) which aims to provide numeric computing facilities in JavaScript and Node.js.

Comment: Or, until that project is finished, you can simply use the original Python package with a small performance overhead with https://www.npmjs.com/package/pymport

Answer (score 46):

Here is Google's [TensorFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/) (previously [deeplearn.js](https://deeplearnjs.org)), which does exactly that, and has built in capacities to train deep neural networks on GPUs using [WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL). You can also [port TensorFlow models to it](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-saved-model.html).

Don't be fooled into thinking this is only for deep learning. It is a fully fledged numerical computing platform with built-in GPU acceleration. It follows the eager "execute as you go" model, like NumPy (and Tensorflow Eager, and PyTorch, and others), not the "define then run" model like TensorFlow. As such, it will feel natural to use to anyone who has used NumPy before.

Here is the very informative GitHub repository: *[TensorFlow.js](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs)*

Comment: Good answer!  deeplearn.js is now called tensorflow.js and can be found at https://js.tensorflow.org

Comment: This seems like the only (current) reasonable answer. All other suggestions for libraries seem to be either experimental or written in pure JavaScript. The major benefit of NumPy is that it's core is written in C, there's no point in just implementing the API of NumPy, you want the performance gains too. But I'd tentatively guess that in the same way that TensorFlow is either a Python or JavaScript wrapper around C++ libraries, it should be possible to wrap the C code of NumPy with a JavaScript API.

Comment: Here's the Node.JS implementation: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node

Comment: Well you'd still have to write the tensor into a javascript array depending on the use case, so it's tough to recommend implementing an entire tf library for its tensor features. Interestingly enough, this may be incorrect, and the engine may use dynamic pointers to create the structure. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61713477/11144990

Comment: The problem with this library is that it is not designed for random access of the tensors without pain. It is designed for execution on a GPU, so all tensors are created on that GPU (or CPU if running local). Which means you can't simply touch element [3][4][5] of a Tensor3D, you have to Tensor3D.arraySync() to download it without a promise, change the value, and then create a new tensor. Yeeeouch.

Comment: What do you mean? @PeterT you can create variable tensors and use set. Also,  I'd like to add that you can only use tensorflow core + backend, which is lighter. I just love tensorflow, I have to say.

Answer (score 8):

I've not tried this, but I found [node-lapack](https://github.com/NaturalNode/node-lapack). Since NumPy gets most of it's speed from using [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms)/[LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) to do everything, this should help. From the readme it looks like it has an array object too, which is essential to not convert between JavaScript and LAPACK on every operation.

Here's a part of their demo:

```javascript
var lapack = require('lapack');

var result = lapack.sgeqrf([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [5, 6, 7]
]);

console.log(result.R);
console.log(result.tau);

result = sgesvd('A', 'A', [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [5, 6, 7]
]);

console.log(result.U);
console.log(result.S);
console.log(result.VT);

result = lapack.sgetrf([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [5, 6, 7]
]);

// See the readme for more
```

It seems to be a pretty direct interface to lapack using the same names, so in that regard it's not as convenient as Numpy, but at least it takes care of array dimensions and stuff and should be about as fast (since most of the work is being done by Lapack in either case).

However, this won't work in a browser, which means everywhere where this is available, Python is probably also available. Personally, I'd stick with Python, which is much more dominant for numerical stuff, unless there's some specific Node functionality Python is missing...

Answer (score 8):

[numjs](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs) is a NumPy-like library in Node.js.

Answer (score 5):

In the same spirit of [Jules's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412537/is-there-a-numpy-like-package-for-node-js-and-if-not-why-not/49213594#49213594) about *deeplearn.js*, tensorflow.js is the continuation of the same project.  To play around with the TensorFlow module in the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop), I installed it globally (FYI - it is usually advised not to do this) using this:

```
npm install --global @tensorflow/tfjs
```

Then, I ran `node` to start the Node.js REPL.

This may differ for you (especially if you decided to install TensorFlow locally), but I entered this to reference the TensorFlow module:

```javascript
var tf = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs')
```

To create a rank 1 tensor (equivalent to a 1-D array in NumPy), try:

```javascript
var x = tf.tensor( [-3,4] )
```

And square it with:

```javascript
x.square().print()
```

You should get `[9,16]` for your output.  See https://js.tensorflow.org for more details.

I would say that tensorflow.js is not only a JavaScript replacement for NumPy, but also for [scikit-learn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scikit-learn), [Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras), and of course, TensorFlow.

Comment: Is there a matrix/array renderer in the similar vein as matplotlib but for JS. I imagine that it would be cool to be able to render the arrays (especially image arrays) in the browser using canvas or webgl.

Comment: yep, plotly.js supports webgl: https://codepen.io/destrada/pen/rmrGYL.  in the link, scattergl is used to make a scatter plot from the data.

Answer (score 3):

The majority of Node.js work seems to be in the web "full stack" universe, with a lot less work being done in areas where fast numeric processing is an advantage.

In the areas where fast numeric processing is an advantage, Python, [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29), etc. probably have a dominant mindshare.

Combine those two facts, and you end up with not a lot of people putting effort into Node.js numeric processing libraries.

Answer (score 1):

scijs's [ndarray](https://github.com/scijs/ndarray) is also good.

```
var mat = ndarray(new Float64Array([1, 0, 0, 1]), [2,2])

//Now:
//
// mat = 1 0
//       0 1
//
```

Answer (score -1):

I started [TS Math](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nexys/math-ts) a very simple and light numerical TypeScript library/package

[TS Math on GitHub](https://github.com/Nexysweb/math-ts)