# How to use jQuery ajax without server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have used jQuery ajax in my html pages.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'search/' + page + '.html',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        $(".searchData").html(data);
        $(".searchData").show("slow");
        $(".searchImage").hide("slow");
    },
    error: function() {
        $(".searchImage").show("slow");
        $(".searchData").hide("slow");
    }
});
```

There is no server. I am accessing my page like `file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sss/Desktop/rrr/search.html` and it works fine in Firefox, but it's not working in Chrome and other browsers, it shows:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

How to do that?

Comment: @PranavRam What do you think the OP has? lol

Comment: possible duplicate of [My XML file is not being by Google Chrome and Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038256/my-xml-file-is-not-being-by-google-chrome-and-internet-explorer) or [Chrome: Disable same origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3102819/1048572)

Answer (score 4):

Because the browser has security measures to prevent it. If you want to work with the file system, you need to set up the browser to allow it.

[How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)